# How do I redirect an asp url with query string to php url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

There is an old link coming to my site that ends with sc_purchase_a.asp?discode=foo&ProID=bar. I want to redirect that to /courses/shop/4u.php?discode=foo. This is what I've done so far, but its not working.

```
RewriteRule ^sc_purchase_a.asp?discode=(\w+)&ProdID=(\w+)/?$ /courses/shop/4u.php?discode=$1 [QSA]
```

This doesnt seem to work.

Based on starkeen's answer, I came up with this, but it is not working and now gives me 500 errors.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /sc_purchase_a\.asp\?discode=([^&]+)&ProID=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /courses/shop/4u.php?discode=%1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Try: /page.php?code=$1 [L]

Answer (score 2):

QueryString is not part of match in RewriteRules pattern. To manupulate query string ,you need to use a RewriteCond

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page\.asp\?code=([^&]+)&id=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page.php?code=%1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Sorry to be an ignoramus, but what do you mean by `{THE_REQUEST}`?

Comment: THE_REQUEST is an apace predefined variable it represents the full request line sent by client to the server ,eg **GET /page.asp?code=foo&id=bar HTTP 1.1**

Comment: This is working fine on my apache server. Please check your error log for info about the error.